# Unable to cast COM object

Tags: quickbooks

Using below code i am trying to read Items data from Quick books using QBFC.

But i am getting error:

Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Interop.QBFC11.IItemSalesTaxRetList'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{C53D1081-9FE4-4569-9181-A9D7E0155907}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).

I have seen this below link;

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsnetsetup/archive/2012/10/05/unable-to-cast-com-object-of-type-system-comobject-to-interface-type.aspx

but this is problem with installing software (after installing).But this issue is diff from issue.

Let me know why...I used same process for getting customer and vendor data...i did not get any error....

code:

```
IItemSalesTaxRet itemRet = default(IItemSalesTaxRet);

IItemSalesTaxRetList itemRetList = default(IItemSalesTaxRetList);

IResponse response = responseSet.ResponseList.GetAt(0);

if ((response.Detail != null))

            {

     itemRetList = (IItemSalesTaxRetList)response.Detail; // here i am getting error

                if ((itemRetList != null))
                {

                    for (int j = 0; j <= itemRetList.Count - 1; j++)
                    {
                        itemRet = itemRetList.GetAt(j);
                        if ((itemRet != null))
                        {


                           if (itemRet.Name != null)
                           {

                                Name = GetStringValue(itemRet.Name);
                              Name = Name.Replace(',', ' ');

                           }
                           else
                          {
                              Name = string.Empty;
                          }


               }
        }
  }
```

Comment: Did you install QBFC11 on the system you are running this on?

Comment: yes i have installed....not even QBFC11.I have tried with QBFC10 also. I am getting same error message.

Answer (score 1):

I see this post is pretty old, but there are thousands of developers using Intuit's SDK having the same/similar problems.
Don't know if this will help, but there are a lot of interfaces in the Quickbooks library that are not supported anymore even though they show up on the onscreen reference. You may even get intellisense showing a method as supported, but they forgot to remove some interfaces when they (re)compiled their dll. I have run into this maddening problem several times - "IItemSalesTaxRetList" appears to be one of those methods they deleted.